# Is it unnecessary to put super() in constructor?

Tags: java, constructor, super

Isn't this one automatically put by the compiler if I don't put it in a subclass's constructor?

That means I don't even need to care about it? In some articles they put it out.

And if I've got one constructor with arguments, will this be the constructor, or does it take a constructor without argument list?

Answer (score 264, accepted):

Firstly some terminology:

- **No-args constructor:** a constructor with no parameters;
- **Accessible no-args constructor:** a no-args constructor in the superclass visible to the subclass. That means it is either public or protected or, if both classes are in the same package, package access; and
- **Default constructor:** the public no-args constructor added by the compiler when there is no explicit constructor in the class.

So all classes have at least one constructor.

Subclasses constructors *may* specify as the first thing they do which constructor in the superclass to invoke before executing the code in the subclass's constructor.

**If the subclass constructor does not specify which superclass constructor to invoke then the compiler will automatically call the accessible no-args constructor in the superclass.**

If the superclass has no no-arg constructor or it isn't accessible then not specifying the superclass constructor to be called (in the subclass constructor) is a compiler error so it *must* be specified.

For example:

```
public class Base { }
public class Derived extends Base { }
```

This is fine because if you add no constructor explicitly Java puts in a public default constructor for you.

```
public class Base { }
public class Derived extends Base { public Derived(int i) { } }
```

Also fine.

```
public class Base { public Base(String s) { } }
public class Derived extends Base { }
```

The above is a compilation error as Base has no default constructor.

```
public class Base { private Base() { } }
public class Derived extends Base { }
```

This is also an error because Base's no-args constructor is private.

Comment: So, I guess the answer to the OP's question in the title is "yes, it is unnecessary to include `super()` in the child constructor", because `super()` is a call to the "accessible no-args constructor".

Comment: "The above is a compilation error as Base has no default constructor." should be modified to "The above is a compilation error as Base has no no-args constructor."

Comment: Depends on how you think.  I think while it is not necessary - i would not say its unnecessary.

Comment: @flow2k It is not a yes or no question. In some cases it is unnecessary as demonstrated by his examples and in some cases it is necessary. super() will be automatically inserted of this(...) or super(...) is not specified. If the super class does not include a no-arg constructor or it is not accessible, then it won't compile. In that case it is necessary to put super(...) and specify the constructor. So it is possible there is not an accessible no arg constructor in which case super is necessary and must have arguments for an accessible constructor.

Comment: @flow2k note that if the super class only has one constructor and it is private, then it is impossible to extend the class (or instantiate the class without reflection) as there is no accessible constructor.

Answer (score 63):

If the super class constructor has no arguments Java automatically calls it for you. If it has arguments you'll get an error.

src: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

Comment: ...and if super class has no constructor whatsoever, it [the default constructor] will also be provided by the compiler. The provided constructor will have the same access level as the super class access level.

Answer (score 29):

Calling the no-arguments super constructor is just a waste of screen space and programmer time. The compiler generates exactly the same code, whether you write it or not.

```
class Explicit() {
    Explicit() {
        super();
    }
}

class Implicit {
    Implicit() {
    }
}
```

---

Update (December 2018):

Writing an explicit `super()` helps navigating the source code in the IDE.

As of December 2018, neither Eclipse nor [IntelliJ](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5581) provide any means of comfortably navigating from the constructor of the derived class to the constructor of the base class.

Comment: The empty no-args Implicit constructor is also unnecessary.

Comment: @Jon In this case, yes. But if you had a constructor with arguments, then the no-arg constructor will not be created by default.

Answer (score 8):

Default parent constructor is called from child default constructor even if you do not call it.

Main

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new B();
    }
}
```

A

```
public class A {

    public A() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}
```

B

```
public class B extends A {

    public B() {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}
```

Prints

```
A
B
```

Answer (score 1):

Any class constructor always calls "super()" if there is not explicitly called super([arguments]), only we keep in mind access of super class constructor while programming...
when we not extends any specific class automatic extends java.lang.Object class

Answer (score -2):

```
abstract class Book
 {
String title;
String author;
Book(String t,String a){
    title=t;
    author=a;
}
abstract void display();

}
```

If super class can have a  No-args constructor .It is good to have a no argument constructor otherwise you have to pass super constructor with parameter .

If the superclass has no no-arg constructor or it isn't accessible then not specifying the superclass constructor to be called (in the subclass constructor) is a compiler error so it must be specified

```
class MyBook extends Book{   
int price ;
public  MyBook(String t,String a,int price){
     super(t,a);
    this.price=price;
}

public void display(){
    System.out.println("Title: "+title);
 System.out.println("Author: "+author); 
System.out.println("Price: "+price);

}
```

}

Comment: First paragraph is a *non sequitur.*