# alpha beta prunning generics, writing an exception

Tags: java

I have to implement the alpha beta prunning algorithm for the game 4Connect. I have to implement the method with generics:

```
public M getBestMove() throws GameException {
```

I don't really know what the statement "throws GameException" means. I tried to write my own exception. but I never did it before, so I could need some help from you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to define custom exception class in Java, the easiest way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776327/how-to-define-custom-exception-class-in-java-the-easiest-way)

Answer (score 0):

`Do I need a try catch block in my method?`

No, since your method throws an exception the client code, the code that calls this method, needs it in a try block.

```
try{
    Move m = getBestMove();
}catch(GameException e){
    //handle the exception
}
```

To answer your other question, you can do whatever you want after you catch the exception, so you can turn the game back on if you want.

Comment: thank you, but do I have to throw the game exception in the method by my self? and can you have a llok over my exception? I don`t think its right.