# OverLimit Exception handling in java

Tags: java, exception

Program to raise an exception stating "Further Transactions Not Possible until clearance of bill." when a customer's unpaid credit card amount cross $2000 or is unpaid upto 45 days. Assume that the current date is `01/12/2015`.

1. Create a custom exception class `OverLimitException` which extends `Exception`.
2. Add a constructor which takes a `Throwable` object, calls the super class constructor using `super()` and prints the output as described in the problem statement.

I created two classes one main and the other account

Account.java

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Account {

String accountNumber;
String accountName;
Double dueAmount;

public Account(String accountNumber, String accountName,Double dueAmount) throws ParseException {
    this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    this.accountName = accountName;
    this.dueAmount = dueAmount;
}

public Account() {
}

public Boolean validate(String dueDate,Double unpaid,Double amount){
    DateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    sf.setLenient(false);
    try{
        Date d = sf.parse(dueDate);
        Date d1 = sf.parse("01/12/2015");
       // long curDate = new Date().getTime();
        long diff =d1.getTime() - d.getTime();
        long daysDiff = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        if(daysDiff > 45 || unpaid > 2000){
            throw new OverLimitException("Further Transactions Not Possible until clearance of bill.");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public void display() {       
    System.out.println("Transaction successsfully completed.");
    System.out.println("Account Number : "+this.accountNumber);
    System.out.println("Account Name : "+this.accountName);
    System.out.println("Unpaid Amount : "+this.dueAmount);
}
}
```

But am getting an error stating

```
 error: cannot find symbol
 throw new OverLimitException("Further Transactions Not Possible until clearance of bill.");
 ^
 symbol: class OverLimitException
```

Can any one please help me solve this problem?

Comment: And hint: you don't want to return **B**oolean, but **b**oolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The valiade function has to throw OverLimitException and you have to define it

```
public Boolean validate(String dueDate,Double unpaid,Double amount) 
      throws OverLimitException{
      ...
      if(daysDiff > 45 || unpaid > 2000){
          throw new OverLimitException("Further Transactions Not Possible  until clearance of bill.");
    }
    ...

}
```

and implement the OverLimitException ; here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776327/how-to-define-custom-exception-class-in-java-the-easiest-way)

```
     public class OverLimitException extends Exception {
         public OverLimitException(String message) {
            super(message);
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

*OverLimitException* is not an exception that comes with Java.

Like the other classes you created, you have to write that class, too; like:

```
public class OverLimitException extends RuntimeException {
```

and provide a constructor that takes a message string for example.