# Exceptions in method declaration in java

Tags: java, exception, throws

I have the following method to implement for an ArrayList, but I'm not sure how to go about treating the exception. If the ArrayList is empty does it automatically throw that exception or do I need to write something in the method?

```
public T removeLast() throws EmptyCollectionException
{
    //TODO: Implement this.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An exception is an object that extends throwable. 
You would write that yourself

```
if(list.isEmpty()){
    throw new EmptyCollectionException("possibly a message here");
} else {
    //your logic here to return a T
}
```

Comment: Correct, but the `else` is silly ;-) See ControlAltDel answer for a better alternative.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't filled in the method, so we can't say for sure. If you used ArrayList.remove(0); on an empty list, it would give you a IndexOutOfBoundsException

In any case, it's never going to throw your custom exception: You need to throw this yourself. You can do this at the top of the method, like

```
public T removeLast() throws EmptyCollectionException
{
  if (myList.size() == 0) throw new EmptyCollectionException("List Is Empty");
  ... //otherwise...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to throw the exception *yourself* if the `ArrayList` is empty.

The `throws EmptyCollectionExceptio` clause in the method signature is only a reminder, for the *calling code*, that `removeLast()` might throw an exception (and should be properly handled).

Answer (score 0):

EmptyCollectionException is not an existing exception. Define a new exception:

```
if(list.IsEmpty()){
throw new EmptyCollectionException("message");
}
```

or use IndexOutOfBoundsException instead, you can also use a `try catch` block:

```
try{

   //Whatever could cause the exception

}catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
   //Handle the exception
   //e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Find me EmptyCollectionException in the JDK. How is it going to throw it? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api

Comment: @ControlAltDel using IndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to [define your custom exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776327/how-to-define-custom-exception-class-in-java-the-easiest-way). That might be:

```
public class EmptyCollectionExceptionextends Exception {
    public EmptyCollectionException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Then you can throw the exception as in some of the other answers posted.

```
public T removeLast() throws EmptyCollectionException
{
  if (myList.size() == 0) throw new EmptyCollectionException("List Is Empty");
  ... //otherwise...
}
```