# When exception occur, what is responsibility of exception class?

Tags: java, exception

When exception occur in try block, catch block will handle it. So what is responsibility of exception class? I found in exception class in Java and only saw some function to provide infomation about exception(???). What is exception class do when exception occur . And if i want to write my own MyException extend Exception, what method i should write in exception class to handle my exception

Comment: To create your own exception you need to invoke the constructor of `Exception`. See [How to define custom exception class in Java, the easiest way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776327/how-to-define-custom-exception-class-in-java-the-easiest-way)

Comment: In the ideal word we log exception information somewhere using any logging framework so we can use them to troubleshoot some issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *What is exception class do when exception occur*

   Nothing.
2. *if i want to write my own MyException extend Exception, what method i write in exception class to handle my exception*

    You don't need to implement anything, but you may want to have constructor to set message and store some relevant information.

Comment: so with FileNotFoundException and ParseException, if i exchange each other, program would working properly (except info it provides), right?

Comment: What do you mean by exchange? If you throw one instead of another? You will break the code because if it catches one exception, doesn't mean it catch another.

Comment: in catch(FileNotFoundException e){ //some code...}, i change to catch( ParseException e){ //some code...} with some code the same in catch. how it would?

Comment: You don't understand what `catch` clause do? It catch specific exception, if you change exception it stops catching old one and starts catching new.

Answer (score 1):

When some code encounters a "problem", it may create an Exception object that describes the problem and throw it to the calling code to say "things didn't go as planned for reason X".

It is the up to the calling code to handle the exception (with a try/catch block) and act appropriately. The exception doesn't say or care about what should be done next.

If you are in a situation where you want to describe a specific issue more precisely that what a "standard" exception allows, you can create your own exception. Say you sell products that can only be sold to people between 20 and 40:

```
throw new AgeLimitException(clientAge, 20, 40);
```

And the client code:

```
try {
  buyProduct();
} catch (AgeLimitException e) {
  showMessage("Your age is " + e.getAge() + " but you must be between " + e.minAge()
            + " and " + e.maxAge() + " to buy this product");
}
```

As you can see, the role of the AgeLimitException is simply to give information about the problem that occurred.

Answer (score 0):

We create User-Defined-Exception class to handle the upcoming exceptions , when a exception occur then it will create the Exception class object ,where we have declared what to do when do do next ,so our program flow or process going on didn't break .

Answer (score 0):

`Exception` class is a type of `Throwable`. It only gives you an exception(an issue that breaks your flow of execution) information.

`Throwable` is also a class & superclass(parent) of all `Error` & `Exception`. Only objects that are instances of this class (or one of its subclasses) are thrown by the Java Virtual Machine or can be thrown by the Java throw statement. Similarly, only this class or one of its subclasses can be the argument type in a catch clause.

Custom Exception: Java provides the facility to create our own exceptions which are basically derived classes of `Exception`.

A Class that represents a use-defined exception

```
class MyException extends Exception 
{ 
    public MyException(String s) 
    { 
        // Call constructor of parent Exception 
        super(s); 
    } 
}
```

A Class that uses above MyException

```
public class Main 
{ 
  // Driver Program 
  public static void main(String args[]) 
  { 
    try
    { 
        // Throw an object of user defined exception 
        throw new MyException("My own exception"); 
    } 
    catch (MyException ex) 
    { 
        System.out.println("Caught"); 

        // Print the message from MyException object 
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage()); 
    } 
  } 
}
```