# Implement my own Java exception

Tags: java, exception

I have to implement my own exception (a `GameException`) which is thrown by the alpha beta algorithm in a nullsumm game.
Is this correct?

```
import java.lang.Exception;

 public class GameException extends Exception { 

     public static final long serialVersionUID = 3654258946527845L;

     public static final String NoValidMoves = "There are noe valid moves!";


    GameException(String Message) {
        super(Message);
    }
    GameException() {

    }

}
```

Comment: I think your code is correct. In addtion to, you may add some custom methods for your exception class. For exaple; you throw an error code and your method matches the error code explanation and return it for exception message. Good luck !

Answer (score 3):

It's correct.

---

FYI

- You don't need to import `java.lang.Exception`. The `java.lang` part means that it is there by default.
- By convention, variables in Java are lowerCamelCase.
- You don't need to make `serialVersionUID` `public`. Any access modifier will work with `Serializable`, so usually `private` is chosen.
- You misspelled "no".

Comment: it **is** calling the no-arg constructor : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054022/unnecessary-to-put-super-in-constructor