# Alternate constructor invocation

Tags: java, constructor

I've been reading an **[article](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7.1)** about constructors in Java and come across the following piece of text:

> Execution of instance variable initializers and instance initializers
>   is performed regardless of whether the superclass constructor
>   invocation actually appears as an explicit constructor invocation
>   statement or is provided automatically. (An alternate constructor
>   invocation does not perform this additional implicit execution.)

It's a bit unclear to me about the sentence in parenthesis. Does that mean if we don't specify the alternate constructor to be invoked explcitly, it won't be called implicitly as `this()`, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [unnecessary to put super() in constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054022/unnecessary-to-put-super-in-constructor)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It's saying that you will always get a call to the `super()` constructor as the first statement in your constructor (unless you use a `this()`, but then that will have a `super()` call as it's first statement - or an alternate call, eventually `super()` will be called).

Consider what happens in the empty constructor of a hypothetical class like `Main` with a `String value` field and three constructors like

```
private String value;

public Main() {
    this(10); // alternate constructor, super() isn't invoked yet.
}

public Main(int val) {
    this(String.valueOf(val)); // alternate constructor, no super() yet
}

public Main(String str) {
    // super(); // <-- will now implicitly or explicitly super()
    this.value = str;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Base s = new Base();
```

will invoke automatically Super() constructor

But alternate constructor like argument constructor will actually will not call `super();`

you have explicitly call  `super()` or `super(argument)` whatever available in the super class

Alternate constructor also includes this() which will call Base() constructor which will not allow super() constructor call and hence initializing will not happen