# Super Function Java with no parameters in superclass

Tags: java, class, inheritance, constructor, super

If I have a superclass `Animal` with no attributes, and then another subclass `Dog` with one attribute, is it valid to use the `super()` method when creating the constructor for the subclass? Here's the example code:

```
public class Animal {
    
    public Animal() { }
}
```

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
    
    public int age;
    public Dog(int age){
        super(); // Do I include this?
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Is there any reason why I should or should not call the `super()` function in the `Dog` class, and does it make a difference? Thanks!

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054022/is-it-unnecessary-to-put-super-in-constructor) could provide you an answer. But short answer is no, you don't have to.

Comment: Unless you have to invoke some piece of code in super, you don't have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7):

> If a constructor body does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation and the constructor being declared is not part of the primordial class Object, then the constructor body implicitly begins with a superclass constructor invocation "`super();`", an invocation of the constructor of its direct superclass that takes no arguments.

This means that, if you don't have an explicit call or does have an explicit call to `super()`, the superclass needs to have a no-arg constructor - either an explicitly declared one, or a default constructor (a no-arg constructor automatically added by the compiler if the class has no other constructors).

As such, if the code compiles with the explicit `super()`, that means the super class does have a no-arg constructor: and so it would also compile and work equivalently if you omitted the `super()`.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to call super() here as no-arg super class constructor gets called by default from subclass.

Only if there is a constructor in super class with some argument, then you need to call it from subclass explicitly if required.

Comment: You are only required to call `super` if there is *no no-arg constructor* in the superclass. There can be constructors in the superclass which take params, but it's fine if there is also a no-arg ctor.